# What will be the sample size to determine the incidence and prevalence when estimated prevalence is 17.93 per 100000?

Tags: sample-size, epidemiology, prevalence

I want to conduct a study to determine the incidence and prevalence of oral cancer in an area. I prefer door to door community based screening by Oral visual examination and refer suspected case for biopsy to confirm.

I have adequate manpower and 12 months of time. Total population is 3169615. Target Population (over 18 years old) is 2460500. Exact prevalence is Unknown. Estimated prevalence is 17.93 per 100000. Estimated Incidence is 13985 (8.9%). Sensitivity of screening method is 88.8% (95% CI: 71.6-96.1).Specificity of screening method is 91.9% (95% CI: 78.3-97.3).
What will be the sample size? How will I calculate the sample size?

Comment: You have provided no details about how precise you need the estimate to be. If you want the *exact* incidence and prevalence, you need to sample everyone in the population. If you don't need to be very precise, you can sample just a few people and have an imprecise estimate.